# Zero a direita - Input

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

Tenho um input text que só recebe número, preciso que no ato em que o usuário digitar um valor, logo em seguida acrescentar o número zero à direita, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Somente na primeira vez ou a cada ve que o utilizador inserir um numero?

Comment: Amigo a cada vez que ele digitar um valor...

Comment: Algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/b15p4f5e/ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.querySelector('#meuInput');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    this.value = this.value + 0;
});
```

A ideia é: a cada vez que uma tecla for despressionada, o valor do `input` deverá receber um `0` no final.

**Exemplo online: https://jsfiddle.net/b15p4f5e/**

Comment: O problema dessa ideia ai é que assim que o usuário digita 1 carácter ele ja implementa um zero na frente, e se no caso o usuário quiser digitar um valor com 3 casas decimas por exemplo...

Comment: @Marzine daí a minha pergunta _"Somente na primeira vez ou a cada ve que o utilizador inserir um numero"_. Então queres que seja inserido um zero, somente uma vez, á direita?

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você poderia usar uma mascara Jquery, como https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/, acho que resolve seu problema.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. Como por exemplo, como realizar esta implementação.